# Linq filter from Collection C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of People and I need to filter it out where "status" property is null.

```
Person p = (from p in house.People where p.status == null)
```

How can I just get the person from the collection whose status is null?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only expect one person which status is `null` you can use `First`/`FirstOrDefault`:

```
Person p = (from p in house.People where p.status == null).FirstOrDefault();
```

or in method syntax

```
Person nullStatusPerson = house.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.status == null);
```

It will be `null` if there is no person which status is `null`.

If you want all persons which status is `null` you could create a collection:

```
List<Person> nullStatusPersons =  house.People.Where(p => p.status == null).ToList();
```

Finally, you can use `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` if it was a bug if there were more than one Person which status is `null`. It will throw an `InvalidOperationException` then.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility the collection has more than one item matching your condition, so you normally want to get the entire matching set and loop over it.

A `List<Person>` would be appropriate to save the matching instances:

```
List<Person> p = (from p in house.People where p.status == null).ToList();
```

If you really expect one, get the first item:

```
Person p = (from p in house.People where p.status == null).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: List<Person> p = (from p in house.People where p.status == null select p).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var person = house.People.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.status==null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may return only one result using [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb291976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Person p = house.People.First(p => p.status == null);
```

This will throw an exception if no element has been found. If you want to avoid this and return `null` instead use `FirstOrDefault`. If you expect exactly one element you can also use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` which will throw an exception if more then one element has been found.